# Yii2 Sphinx search greater than less or Less than less condition OR "BETWEEN"

Tags: mysql, yii2, sphinx

```
$totalGeneralDownload = $squery->from('general_materials','general_materials_delta')
                                    ->match
                                    (
                                        (new MatchExpression())
                                        ->match([$param => $searchTitle])
                                        ->andfilterMatch(['and','download_count>=100','download_count<=100'])

                                    )
                                    ->showMeta(true)
                                    ->search();
```

This is my sphinx code, can anyone let me know how to use Between in Sphinx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have R&D on it and find out that sphinx only text search not giving between type clauses so i think you should get id and then you have to filter by between clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Sphinx not provide between clause so we have to manage in our code.
once you get id from sphinx and then you have to filter by your code and then get the result.